# Integral with Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion. I have to show that
$$\int_0^t \frac{B_u}{u}du$$
converges almost surely with $t\to \infty$. Honestly, I do not know how to proceed, since I am new to the field of stochastic processes, what I tried to do is to say that, for every $s$, we have
$$ \int_0^t \frac{B_u}{u}du = \int_0^s \frac{B_u}{u}du + \int_s^t \frac{B_u}{u}du $$
but then, by definition of Brownian motion,
$$\int_s^t \frac{B_u}{u}du = \int_s^t \frac{B_u-B_s}{u}+\frac{B_s}{u} du=\int_s^t \frac{B_u-B_s}{u}+ln(s)B_s$$
where as first term we have something similar to the initial integral, even if probably I have just made things more complex. **Could you give me some hints?**

EDIT:

There was a misunderstanding here, the statement proposed by the book where I've found the problem was instead referring to the convergence of the integral in the 0 extremal, which is much simpler. Thus, it is difficult to know wether this statement is true or not.

Comment: Got a reference for the statement? I'd doubt this integral converges to some finite value.

Comment: No it was my error

Comment: since $B_{u}\sim\sqrt{u}B_{1}$ I would expect the integral behaves like $\int_{0}^{t}u^{-1/2} du$ which would not converge for $t\to\infty$

Comment: Your integral is normally distributed, with mean $0$ and variance $2t$. The a.s. large $t$ limit, were it to exist, would also be normally distributed. But the variance blows up as $t\to\infty$.